# Functional Equation in the rationals: $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)-f(x+y)+1$

Tags: functional-equations

> Find all the possible functions $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ such that
> $$f(1)=2$$
> and
> $$f(xy)=f(x)f(y)-f(x+y)+1\text.$$

I managed to find the function for the set of natural number, by putting $x=1$ and $y=n$. From it, I have that
$$f(n+1)=f(n)+1\text,$$
which means that $f(n)$ is an arithmetic progression of natural numbers.

I am stuck with generalizing this into the set of rational number, any hit will be appreciated.

Comment: One more: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96325/finding-the-function

Comment: how can I find if my question is duplicate

Comment: You can check here: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f(xy)%3Df(x)f(y)-f(x%2By)%2B1%24&p=1

Comment: @VIVID that's a duplicate, a triplicate, and a quadruplicate!