# functional equation problem in competition: $ f ( x y ) = f ( x ) f ( y ) - f ( x + y ) + 1 $

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all $ f : \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q $ such that $ f ( 1 ) = 2 $ and
> $$ f ( x y ) = f ( x ) f ( y ) - f ( x + y ) + 1 $$
> for all $ x , y \in \mathbb Q $.

thank you very much!

Comment: Just putting $y = 1$ yields $f(x+1) = f(x) + 1$.

Comment: yes i got it... but then i can't get to anywhere...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About finding the function such that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)-f(x+y)+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96316/about-finding-the-function-such-that-fxy-fxfy-fxy1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $y=1$. Than we have 
$$f(x)=f(x)\cdot f(1)- f(x+1)+1$$
Hence 
$$f(x)=2f(x)- f(x+1)+1$$
Hence
$$f(x+1)=f(x)+1$$.
So we have $f(0)=1$.
Now we say $x=-y$, we have 
$$f(-x^2)=f(x)f(-x)$$
When we have
$$0=f(-1)=f(-2\cdot \frac{1}{2}) = f(-2) f(\frac{1}{2})- f(-\frac{3}{2}) +1$$ 
So we have
$$0= -1\cdot f(\frac{1}{2}) - f(\frac{1}{2}) +3$$
Hence 
$$0= -1(2\cdot f(\frac{1}{2})-3) $$
Hence $f(\frac{1}{2})=1$
You need more help?

In general we have for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ 
\begin{align*}
0&=f(-1)\\
&=f(-x\cdot \frac{1}{x}) \\
&=f(-x) \cdot f(\frac{1}{x}) - f(-x+\frac{1}{x})+1\\
&= (-x+1)\cdot f( \frac{1}{x}) -  f(\frac{1}{x}) +x\\
&= -x \cdot( f(\frac{1}{x}) -1)
\end{align*}

Comment: sorry, i don't understand why $f(3/2)$ disappaer and we have $0=3f(1/2)-f(1/2)$...? sorry for a dumb question...

Comment: @foxface sry i forgot a minus somewhere corrected it

Comment: i see... , but what's wrong with my solution: put $x=2, y=1/2$, we have $f(1)=2=f(2)f(1/2)-f(2+1/2)+1$, but $f(2)=3$ and $f(2+1/2)=2+f(1/2)$, simplifying yields $f(1/2)=3/2$...

Comment: Thank you very much! I solve it!! thanks for answering me:)