# Functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)-f(xy)+1$

Tags: functional-equations

I'm new to solving functional equations and found the following functional equation from a collection of functional equations.

Find all functions $f: \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{R}$ for $$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)-f(xy)+1$$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{Q}$.

By substituting $x,y\to 0$, we get
$$f(0)=f(0)^2-f(0)+1$$
$$f(0)^2-2f(0)+1=0$$
$$f(0)=1$$
And then doing the substitution $x\to 1,\ y\to -1$, we get
$$f(0)=f(1)f(-1)-f(-1)+1$$
$$f(1)f(-1)-f(-1)=0$$
$$f(-1)(f(1)-1)=0$$
$$f(-1)=0\vee f(1)=1$$

So, no we have three possible cases to consider and I have no idea on how to proceed on any of them.
I would appreciate any hints before giving the full solution as in the best case that's all I need right now.

Comment: Putting $y=1$ gives you a relationship $f(x + 1) = f(x) C + 1$ where $C = f(1) - 1$. That's enough to determine $f$ in the integers up to a constant. I'm sure you can work it out from there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About finding the function such that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)-f(x+y)+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96316/about-finding-the-function-such-that-fxy-fxfy-fxy1)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/351068, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2394682, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/96325  – all found with [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24%7B+f%28x%2By%29%3Df%28x%29f%28y%29-f%28xy%29%2B1+%7D%24&page=1&tm=0&domains=a%2C)

Comment: @MartinR Well those have the added clause that f(1)=2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)^2-f(0)+1$ so $(f(0)-1)^2=0$, $\therefore f(0)=1$.
Let $f(1)=a+1$, then noting that $f(n+1)=af(n)+1$ \begin{align}f(2)&=f(1+1)=a^2+a+1\\
f(4)&=f(3+1)=\cdots=a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1\\
&=f(2+2)=f(2)^2-f(4)+1\end{align} $$\therefore 2f(4)=f(2)^2+1$$ Solving for $a$ gives $a=-1,0,1$.

If $a=-1$, $f(1)=0$, then $f(n)=\begin{cases}1&n \textrm{ odd}\\0&n \textrm{ even}\end{cases}$. This gives the formula $f(x+1)=1-f(x)$. This function does not extend to $\mathbb{Q}$ otherwise $f(1)=f(2\times\tfrac{1}{2})=f(2)f(\tfrac{1}{2})-f(2+\tfrac{1}{2})+1$, which is the same as $0=f(\tfrac{1}{2})-f(\tfrac{1}{2})+1$.

If $a=0$, then $f(n)=1$ for all $n$. This extends to all of $\mathbb{Q}$ by noting that $f(x+1)=f(x)f(1)-f(x)+1=1$.

If $a=1$, then $f(n)=n+1$ for all $n$. This extends as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96316/about-finding-the-function-such-that-fxy-fxfy-fxy1) to $\mathbb{Q}$.

The last two functions $f(x)=x+1$ and $f(x)=1$ satisfy the general formula for all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

Our equation is. for all values of x and y belonging to the set of rational numbers there exists f(x+y) = f(x)f(y) - f(xy) + 1, such that f(x+y) is real.
or, f(xy) = f(x)f(y) - f(x+y) +1
if y = 0 then  f(x*0) = f(x)f(0) - f(x+0) +1
or, f(o) = f(x)f(0) - f(x) +1
or, f(0) -1 = f(x)f(0) - f(x) = f(x){f(0)-1}
or, f(x) = 1
therefore, f(x+y) = 1.
This is the only solution I guess. [I am not sure though. :) ]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please use MathJax for your formulas. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).